# File not being renamed in Android 10

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-10.0

I wrote a solution for renaming files, but nothing happens in Android 10, although in 11 and above it is renamed normally.

```
public class PathDiv {
public static String dev(String path){
    return path.replaceAll("^(.*)/.*?$","$1");
}

public static void renameFilesInDir(String path, String dirIn, String ext) {

    File checkFile = new File(path);
        if (checkFile.isFile()) {
            try {
                checkFile.renameTo(new File(dirIn, ext));

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
}
```

path: /storage/emulated/0/Music/04. Kasger - Highland.mp3 dirIn: /storage/emulated/0/Music ext: Highland.mp3

```
PathDiv.renameFilesInDir(songItem.realUri,PathDiv.dev(songItem.realUri),newName.toString())
```

What's the problem?

Comment: This class helps me a lot, there's a method called rename check it out : https://github.com/Blankj/AndroidUtilCode/blob/66a4c0488ca6da273098058d70dabb0fe9b9bd8d/lib/utilcode/src/main/java/com/blankj/utilcode/util/FileUtils.java#L110

Comment: Thanks of course, but the rename method doesn't work Android 10

Comment: you've tried that code ? and still didn't work ?

Comment: Yes, of course, I tried, but nothing happened during the renaming

Comment: It is strange that you dont talk about File.exists() and File.canRead() and File.canWrite() like proposed in your other post.

Comment: Also it is strange that you omit the needed request for legacy external storage.

Comment: Confusing: using a variable with the name ext for a file name.

Comment: `lic static String dev(String path){
    return path.replaceAll("^(.*)/.*?$","$1");
}` Why are you posting such unreadable code? What should we do with it?

Comment: Have you tried `requestLegacyExternalStorage` ?

Answer (score 0):

In Android 10 and Higher Version of android, you can't `Rename` or `Delete` directly.
For `Rename` or `Delete` a media file you want to send a request.

Here Read [Android Official Document](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore#createWriteRequest(android.content.ContentResolver,%20java.util.Collection%3Candroid.net.Uri%3E)) how to create a request

For your information, to Delete a media file Dependency [Available here](https://github.com/jcredking/Delete1) you can use it easily it's created by me

`checkFile.renameTo(new File(dirIn, ext));` It Also Works for this you want to add `ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION` permission in your app but before using this permission please refer to Google Play Police Update